# How can I change image sort order in react-native-image-crop-picker?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-image-picker

First of all, I just wanna say I'm newbie in native interface.

For now, I'm testing [`react-native-image-crop-picker`](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) in iOS platform and made some example.

When I open `ImagePicker` in example, latest image is shown bottom and oldest is top. This sort order is same with native photo app.

[image: image sort order]

Here are my question. **Is it possible to change order inverse?** Is there options for this?

Comment: currently no, we have no control over this

Comment: @SelmiKarim Oh. thank you for answering this question :) Is this not allowed by iOS? or just not implemented feature in react-native-image-crop-picker?

Answer (score 1):

The library recently added a [sortOrder](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/commit/33fd5265e065006f1e5228d5e28ad575182f1310) flag of type 'none' | 'asc' | 'desc'.